# Irrigating with recycled water: Permissible levels of Na Cl EC SAR BOD etc per water analysis of the water source

Tags: government, city

Am looking for  databases describing minimum standards for recycled water for irrigation?

In terms of permissible levels of Na Cl EC SAR BOD etc per water analysis of the water source.

Comment: What kind of "standards" are you looking for? Pipe diameters? Chemicals? Government quotas? For what country?

Comment: Permissible levels of Na Cl EC SAR BOD etc per water analysis of the water source

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Food and Agriculture Organization (FAO) of the UN has numerous datasets and papers relating to crop production. This paper 'Water Quality in Agriculture" discusses recommendations in a wide variety of aspects of irrigation. -

http://www.fao.org/docrep/003/t0234e/T0234E01.htm

The FAO's AQUASTAT datasets cover information on water resources per country:

http://www.fao.org/nr/water/aquastat/main/index.stm

Within these datasets are data related to waste water treatment for crop production use.

http://www.fao.org/nr/water/aquastat/wastewater/index.stm